# configure: error: Need pkg-config to enable libusb support

Tags: yocto, imx6, network-printers

I'm new to yocto, my goal is to add a printer driver to the yocto image of imx6 so that we can access the priter from the board. i was trying a build, following the instructions at IMXLXYOCTOUG.PDF.

```
$ DISTRO=fsl-imx-xwayland MACHINE=imx6qsabresd source fsl-setup-release.sh -b build_dir
$ source setup-environment build_dir
$ bitbake fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx
```

the basic build was successful, i brought up the board with gui, things were fine.
i wanted to add printer support to the image, so ive added meta-printing (https://github.com/rossburton/meta-printing) layer. i've updated bblayer.conf

```
BBFILES ?= ""
BBLAYERS = " \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/poky/meta-poky \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-3rdparty \
  ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-freescale-distro \
  **${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-printing \**
```

as per the instruction in README from github.

Later after booting i was not able to access lp command to print some sample file with the printer. so i added

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cups"
```

in local.conf file which is giving me this error below..

```
| checking for posix_spawn... yes
| checking for tm_gmtoff member in tm structure... yes
| checking for st_gen member in stat structure... no
| checking for removefile... no
| configure: error: Need pkg-config to enable libusb support.
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/jifri/on_board/yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build_dir/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/cups/2.1.4-r0/cups-2.1.4/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/jifri/on_board/yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/build_dir/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/cups/2.1.4-r0/temp/log.do_configure.8342)
ERROR: Task (/home/jifri/on_board/yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/meta-printing/recipes-printing/cups/cups_2.1.4.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 5414 tasks of which 5399 didn't need to be rerun and 2 failed.

Summary: 2 tasks failed:
  /home/jifri/on_board/yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/meta-epson/recipes-epson/bbepson/bbepson_0.1.bb:do_compile
  /home/jifri/on_board/yocto/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/meta-printing/recipes-printing/cups/cups_2.1.4.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 4 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

i have the pkg-config installed on my host PC

```
$ pkg-config --version
0.29.1

$ sudo apt-get install libusb-0.1-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libusb-0.1-4 is already the newest version (2:0.1.12-28).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  snap-confine snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
[sudo] password for eldaas: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libusb-1.0-0-dev is already the newest version (2:1.0.20-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  snap-confine snapd-login-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
```

Any idea why
configure: error: Need pkg-config to enable libusb support.
is happening.

or
is it the right way / is there any better methord to get the lp command running on imx6 through yocto. so that i can access the printer..

any input is apretiated..
Thank you.

Comment: the pkg-config that is missing is probably not the one of your host system but the yocto native one.  Is the meta-layer you added of the same release as the other yocto layers?  Last release of this meta-printing layer is the Sumo release, what's rather old.  But most recipes are rather okay in openembedded-core (http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=cups)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the same. actually I've added meta-printing layer to get the access to cups. but cups were already existing along with the meta layer in poky (imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-extended/cups). so I removed meta-printing layer & then updated build/conf/local.conf with

IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " cups"

This worked for me and after booting I was able to use lp, lpadmin etc.. commands on my imx6 board.